# How to change FlagEnumEditor Color in Telerik WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I am using WPF Telerik FlagEnumEditor in my column named *Statistiken*. FlagEnumEditor enables me to store any combination of the values that are defined in a enumerator.

The problem I am facing is that I can't change its color. I would like it to be transparent or white, just like all the other columns in my RadGridView are.

I have set the FlagEnumEditor BorderBrush and Background to Transparent and some other colors, but nothing happens. Am I missing something ? I don't understand why the color does not change here. How can I change the color of column *Statistiken* to be the same color as column *Datentyp* ?

[image: columns]

Stitistiken Column XAML Source Code:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="CheckComboBoxColumn"
                            Header="Statistiken"
                            IsReadOnly="True">
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
              <telerik:FlagEnumEditor BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                      Background="Transparent"
                                      Margin="-4,0,-2,0"
                                      Value="{Binding Aggregates, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      EnumType="viewModels:Aggregates" />
        </DataTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Enum Aggregates:

```
[Flags]
public enum Aggregates
{
    All = -1,
    None = 0,
    Avg = 1,
    Count = 2,
    Min = 4,
    Max = 8,
    Sum = 16
}
```

---

Datentyp Column XAML Source Code, but here I am using RadComboBox as I don't need to combine Enum values:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Datentyp">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <telerik:RadComboBox BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                  Background="Transparent"
                                  Margin="-5,0,-2,0"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ColumnTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding ColumnType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
             </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <telerik:RadComboBox BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                   Background="Transparent"
                                   Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ColumnTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   SelectedItem="{Binding ColumnType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

ps. I am also open for solutions with the same effect as FlagEnumEditor.

Comment: You're probably looking for this http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/api/html/p_telerik_windows_controls_gridviewcolumn_headercellstyle.htm

Comment: @Aybe I don't think it is HeaderCellStyle but CellStyle (GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle) or CellEditTemplate. But still I can't manage to do it right.

Comment: You don't think, but did you try ?

Comment: Hi @Aybe yes I tried. But it changes only the Header color of the column to white, but then I can't see the font, everything disappears.

Comment: How is the *Datentyp* column defined?

Comment: @mm8 I have added the source code of Datentyp column. DatentypColumn does not need to combine values for Enums that is why it is implemented a bit differently.

Comment: How does the FlagEnumEditor column look if you remove the BorderBrush and Background attributes from your XAML?

Comment: @mm8 nothing changes. I think that this is a bug from Telerik Framework.

Comment: What Telerik theme are you using?

Comment: @mm8 I am using the Visual Studio 2013 Theme.

Comment: The controls will look the same if you remove the BorderBrush and Background attributes from the RadComboBox elements in your XAML.

Comment: @mm8 If I remove the two mentioned attributes from RadComboBox the Datentyp column will then look grey instead of white. Here is a link to the image [link](http://i.imgur.com/HqWcVEu.png)

Comment: Yes, that's my point. Do you want them both to be white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an implicit `RadDropDownButton` style to the `Resources` property of the `FlagEnumEditor` to change its colours:

```
<telerik:FlagEnumEditor Margin="-4,0,-2,0"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Value="{Binding Aggregates, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        EnumType="viewModels:Aggregates">
    <telerik:FlagEnumEditor.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadDropDownButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:RadDropDownButton}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </telerik:FlagEnumEditor.Resources>
</telerik:FlagEnumEditor>
```

Comment: Nice, this did the trick. In design time I can't see the font but at runtime everything works fine. But why is the TargetType RadDropDownButton ?

Comment: It is a control that the FlagEnumEditor uses under the hood.

Comment: Do you maybe know if I can fix the design time ? In design time its totally blank.  Image: [link](http://i.imgur.com/krEg3Yq.png)

Comment: There is one big problem with this solution, every time I open Visual Studio I get the exception: `Exception: Cannot find resource named 'Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadDropDownButton'. Resource names are case sensitive.`

Comment: I solved the design time problem by setting a implicit style in the resources of my usercontrol: 
`<Style TargetType="telerik:RadDropDownButton"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:RadDropDownButton}}">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Transparent" />
            </Style>`

although explicit style would be better (but can't set it).

Comment: Was speaking too fast. The above comment does not work at runtime as I don't see any font :(

Comment: Moving the style to the RadGridView resources solved the problem.